# Double integration of area bounded by a region question

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Here is the given question $$\int \int _s^{ }\ \frac{y}{x}e^{x^2-y^2dA}$$ where S is the region bounded by the hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = 1$ ,$x^2-y^2=4$ and the lines $x=2y$ , $x=\sqrt{\ 2}y$.
Take $x= u\sec v$ and $y = u\tan v$ for $u>0$ and $0<v< \frac{\ \pi }{2}$

I could have solved this had there not be a requirement for substitution, with the substitution, I'm really confused how to approach this question. I substituted with the given expression of x and y for all the above curves and this is what i end up with $$u^2(sec^{2}\ v -tan^{2}\ v)=1, u^2(sec^{2}\ v -tan^{2}\ v)=4 , sec\ v=2\tan\ v, and \sec v=\sqrt{\ 2}\ \tan v  $$

The question doesn't require the evaluation of the integral, we only need to set the limits for it, I'm facing difficluty graphing it however, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $\sec^2v-\tan^2v=1$ so you get $u^2=1,u^2=4$. Since $u>0$, you get $u=1,u=2$ respectively.

$\sec v=k\tan v\implies\sin v=\frac1k$. Putting $k=2,\sqrt2$, we get $\sin v=\frac12,\frac1{\sqrt2}$. Since $v\in(0,\pi/2),v=\pi/6,\pi/4$ respectively.

Thus your transformed region is bounded by the lines $u=1,2$ and $v=\pi/6,\pi/4$ in the $uv$ plane. Now all that remains is to transform the integrand.

Comment: Omg thank you so much, seriously bless you

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Main is to calculate intersection points, after which we have

$$\int\limits_{x_0}^{x_1}\int\limits_{\frac{x}{2}}^{\sqrt{x^4-1}}+\int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2}\int\limits_{\frac{x}{2}}^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}+\int\limits_{x_2}^{x_3}\int\limits_{\sqrt{x^2-1}}^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}$$
where $x_0=\sqrt{x_1}, x_1=\frac{1+\sqrt{65}}{8},x_2=\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}},x_3=\sqrt{2}$